# Jenkins: custom jar dependency issue

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm creating a jar through a project and copied the jar to `c:\mylib\test-automation-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.taf</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-automation-library</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Test Automation Library</name>
  <description>Test Automation Library</description>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

Now, I'm running the test scripts through Jenkins.In the Jenkins job of test scripts, I included the following pre-build step install the library:

```
install:install-file
 -Dfile=c:\mylib\test-automation-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
 -DgroupId=com.mycompany.taf 
 -DartifactId=test-automation-library
 -Dversion=0.0.1 
 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This installs the jar to maven local repository (where are the scripts are supposed to run) and build is successful in the POM file of the test-scripts, I included the following dependency for the above library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.taf</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-automation-library</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If I do maven install (of the test-scripts project) through Jenkins, I'm hitting the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany.taf:test-automation-library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Is it something wrong with the dependency? I tried the with all different options and also googled it, but was not able to figured out what the problem was. I'm really blocked here. any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Rams.

Answer (score 0):

Rams,

Your command reads:

```
install:install-file
-Dfile=c:\mylib\test-automation-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.taf
-DartifactId=test-automation-library
-Dversion=0.0.1
-Dpackaging=jar
```

Your version number is missing the `-SNAPSHOT` qualifier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hmm I tried it, but I still see the same problem :(.

Comment: Need more info then. What is local repo set to for Jenkins job config?

Comment: I'm using default repo and also using "Use default maven settings"  in the Jenkin's config file. The pre-build step is getting successfully installed:

Comment: @Rams,

Do you have your own instance of Maven or Artifactory setup? If so, then deploy the file into there instead of installing to your local file system. If not, please do so - it's good practice in general, and will resolve your problem strategically. The following article is kinda old but gives good explanation of the benefits and steps to proceed.

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository

Answer (score 0):

@333kenshin, this is continuation to my previous comment to your question.

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ test-automation-library ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\AmzonPOCTest1\test-automation-    library\target\test-automation-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to          C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\taf\test-automation-library\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\test-automation-library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 17.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-23T03:38:39-07:00`enter code here`
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  enter code here
```

FYI: I logged into my windows PC non-admin user. I believe it does not matter.

Comment: Do you have your own instance of Maven or Artifactory setup? If so, then deploy the file into there instead of installing to your local file system. If not, please do so - it's good practice in general, and will resolve your problem strategically. The following article is kinda old but gives good explanation of the benefits and steps to proceed. theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository